# Using git to identify all modified functions in a revision

Tags: git, function, diff, history, revision

Is there a good way to use git to identify all the modified functions in each revision in the history?  I've tried using the -p switch, but it doesn't seem to work in the same way that svn's show-c-function parameter works.

My assumption is that I'll want to use "git diff HEAD~i HEAD~i-1 -p" for increasing values of i.  Am I missing some parameters that will help identify diff's best guess on the functions that were modified?

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly what you're looking for? What is the show-c-function behavior from Subversion that you're trying to replicate? How would you like it to identify functions changed? What would you want the output to look like?

Comment: For each revision, if a .c file was affected and some change occurred inside of a function, I'd like to have the corresponding function definition.  For example, if int foo()'s body was changed, I'd like to see "int foo()" in a similar fashion to svn's show-c-function.

Comment: I wonder if something specifically built for javascript was there. that would be great

Comment: For Java, see prototype at https://github.com/monperrus/git-api-diff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty attempt at what I think you're going for. It does a `git log` to show all revisions, `-p` to include the diff in the log, a `grep` to only include the lines containing the commit ID and the hunk headers, and uses `sed` to filter out the line numbers, leaving only the guess at the function name that Git writes after the hunk header.

```
git log -p | grep -E '^(commit|@@)' | sed 's/@@.*@@//'
```

Comment: This solution is outdated and doesn't work on git version >= 2.7.4. Could you please update it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a **magic chant** to list functions within a **`git diff` <sup>*</sup>**

```
git diff |                  \
grep -E '^(@@)' |           \
grep "(" |                  \
sed 's/@@.*@@//' |          \
sed 's/(.*//' |             \
awk -F " " '{print $NF}' |  \
uniq
```

...and what it does is...

> 1. Picks the current diff,
> 2. next picks only lines with "hunk-headers" ,
> 3. next picks only lines with opening parenthesis (as potentially containing function names),
> 4. next ignores the hunk headers,
> 5. next ignores the text after the opening parenthesis,
> 6. next picks only the word immediately before the opening parenthesis,
> 7. and lastly ignores multiple occurrences of the same word in the list.

**Voila!** you have a list of functions being modified by the current `git diff`.

---

<sup>* Verified using `git version 2.7.4` on Ubuntu 16.04 running bash.</sup>

Comment: Also, it doesn't work if the function definition is printed in the diff as then it isn't printed as a header.  It works well to extract from the headers.

Comment: For this to work, you mist have a `.gitattributes` file specifying the language per file so diff finds the right headers.  Instructions on creating one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7347993/3854385

Comment: Also for C/C++ can improve by stripping leading * &

Answer (score 0):

You can list all modified functions in a revision by using git textconv filters. The idea is to create a specific filter that lists all functions/methods, and for all functions, a checksum of the body. This gives this kind of filtered textconv view:

```
m() 12
bar() 42
```

(here `m()` is a function signature, `12` is a checksum of its body))

When `git diff` uses this filter on the two versions before and after the revision:

- if a function is added, a line is added in the diff

Example: foo is added

```
m() 12
+ foo() 24 
bar() 42
```

- if a function is modified, the checksum changes, and a line is updated in the diff

Example: the body of foo is modified

```
m() 12
- foo() 23 
+ foo() 24 
bar() 42
```

How to do that?

1. Create the filter: [java-ls-methods.groovy](https://github.com/monperrus/misc/blob/master/java-ls-methods.groovy) is an implementation of such a filter using Groovy and [Spoon](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon)
2. Register this filter in git: `git config diff.java-ls-methods.textconv /home/path/to/java-ls-methods.groovy`
3. Associate this filter with Java files: `echo "*.java diff=java-ls-methods" >> .gitattributes`
4. Make the diff: `git diff` (diff against last commit) or `git diff master` (diff against another branch)
5. Once your diff is done, comment the line in `.gitattributes` to go back to a normal diff

Credits: solution inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16929266

Comment: Too little information here. Big jump from git to groovy/Spoon. Also this seems java related?

Comment: Oh, you pass the source code through a filter, before doing diff. Didn't know that functionality existed, thanks. That means I could use black as a filter when diff:ing python code? Hmm