# make git diff output changed function names only

Tags: git, bash, diff, git-diff

I notice that when I do git diff it would display the function name that was changed...

Is there a way to make it so that it ONLY lists the function names that got changed and not the other diff contents

Ie. I'm looking for something similar to the --name-only option, except that I want it to be the names of the changed functions instead of the changed files

Comment: `git diff` will only show the function name if the beginning of the function name happens to be in the surrounding context of a changed line. `git` itself does not track such (language-dependent) information.

Comment: You might want to use `git diff --function-context` for a start

Comment: Try `git diff | grep -E '^(@@)' | grep "(" | sed 's/@@.*@@//' | sed 's/(.*//' | awk -F " " '{print $NF}' | uniq` ?... How does it work? Details in this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39439045/319204).

Comment: Use `git diff -W` and `grep -E -A1`