# How can I use Git to identify function changes across different revisions of a repository?

Tags: ruby, git, bash, github, version-control

I have a repository with a bunch of C files. Given the SHA hashes of two commits,

`<commit-sha-1>` and `<commit-sha-2>`,

I'd like to write a script (probably bash/ruby/python) that detects which functions in the C files in the repository have changed across these two commits.

I'm currently looking at the documentation for [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), [git commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) and [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff). If anyone has done something similar before, could you give me some pointers about where to start or how to proceed.

Comment: Might be worth checking out what output it provides for your changes, but the `-W`/`--function-context` flag to `gif diff` might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721447/using-git-to-identify-all-modified-functions-in-a-revision).

Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git diff | \
grep -E '^(@@)' | \
grep '(' | \
sed 's/@@.*@@//' | \
sed 's/(.*//' | \
sed 's/\*//' | \
awk '{print $NF}' | \
uniq
```

Explanation:

> 1: Get diff
>
> 2: Get only lines with hunk headers; if the 'optional section heading' of a hunk header exists, it will be the function definition of a modified function
>
> 3: Pick only hunk headers containing open parentheses, as they will contain function definitions
>
> 4: Get rid of '@@ [old-file-range] [new-file-range] @@' sections in the lines
>
> 5: Get rid of everything after opening parentheses
>
> 6: Get rid of '*' from pointers
>
> 7: [See 'awk']: Print the last field (i.e: column) of the records (i.e: lines).
>
> 8: Get rid of duplicate names.

Comment: You can mark your own answer so that it will benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look too good but you could combine `git` with your
favorite tagging system such as `GNU global` to achieve that. For
example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

global -f main.c | awk '{print $NF}'  | cut -d '(' -f1 | while read i
do
    if [ $(git log -L:"$i":main.c HEAD^..HEAD | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
    then
        printf "%s() changed\n" "$i"
    else
        printf "%s() did not change\n" "$i"
    fi
done
```

First, you need to create a database of functions in your project:

```
$ gtags .
```

Then run the above script to find functions in `main.c` that were
modified since the last commit. The script could of course be more
flexible, for example it could handle all `*.c` files changed between 2 commits as reported by `git diff --stats`.

Inside the script we use `-L` option of `git log`:

> ```
>   -L <start>,<end>:<file>, -L :<funcname>:<file>
>
>        Trace the evolution of the line range given by
>        "<start>,<end>" (or the function name regex <funcname>)
>        within the <file>. You may not give any pathspec
>        limiters. This is currently limited to a walk starting from
>        a single revision, i.e., you may only give zero or one
>        positive revision arguments. You can specify this option
>        more than once.
> ```