# Git - Get method/function names of the file in which changes are made

Tags: git, function, methods, history

How do get the function/method names after doing changes in the c# files.

Comment: Please: the edit was done in good faith: you don't put a tag in the title. No need to revert it.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/6309: I assure you, this is the best practice followed around here. I will leave you edit the title of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that [`userdiff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1ab631647e3addd247c5482e8a3d4c9df7978c62/userdiff.c#L146-L160) does include csharp, all you need to add is a `.gitattributes` file (at the root of your repo) with:

```
*.cs diff=csharp
```

Then a `git diff` will show the function names

With that `.gitattributes` in place, you can [extract the functions names after a diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39439045/6309):

```
git diff |                  \
grep -E '^(@@)' |           \
grep "(" |                  \
sed 's/@@.*@@//' |          \
sed 's/(.*//' |             \
awk -F " " '{print $NF}' |  \
uniq
```

Comment: I need list of method names using git command like list of files name shown for git ls-files -m