# Can Git show history for selected lines?

Tags: git

I have a large file where, somewhere in the middle, there is a function that I know has been modified several times. `git annotate` or `blame` will show the most recent commit for each line but if I'm right, it will show *only* the most recent one, not a list of other commits that affected that line before.

So is there a command in Git where I could say something like **show me commits that affected lines 250..260 in file XYZ**?

Comment: not line, but git log <paths>… - show only commits that affect the specified paths. maybe it helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I view the change history of a method/function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4781405/11343)

Comment: Thanks @CharlesB, I found some good advice there and posted it as an answer here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve the commit log for a specific line in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments in [Git - how do I view the change history of a method/function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4781405/11343), doing

```
git gui blame <file>
```

and then right-clicking a line and selecting *Blame Parent Commit* does what I need.

Answer (score 18):

phpStorm can do this.
Select the lines -> right-click -> Git -> Show History for Selection

Comment: what an awesome feature! Thanks for bringing it to my attention!!

Comment: intellij does it too

Answer (score 7):

```
git show $(git blame XYZ -L 250,260 | awk '{print $1}')
```

[Every line of code is always documented.](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2014/02/hidden-documentation/) via [@mislav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11687/mislav)

Comment: If only the results were chronological.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's not possible. You will need to write a script around git blame. You can find a [bash example of such a script on GitHub](https://github.com/renard/git-line-history).

Answer (score 1):

Select line -> Right-click->Git->Annotate

Comment: this doesnt answer the question as it will only show the most recent commit to affect a single line.

Answer (score 1):

this fonctionnality made me switch to IntelliJ Idea.
With IntelliJ you can select lines, right clic -> git -> Show history for selection
[image]