# IntelliJ's "Show history for selection" feature on Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ there's the option to select some code then right click -> 'Git' -> 'Show history for selection', which will show the commits on which the **selected lines** did change alongside with the changes made.

Is there a plugin or some way to achieve the same thing in VS Code?

EDIT: I'm only asking if there exists a plugin that does this, I'm not asking for "what you think is best". If there's a single plugin that does **exactly** what I'm asking for, that would be the answer.

Comment: [gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens)

Comment: @user Can you please elaborate how can I achieve that with Gitlens, I have the plugin installed but I don't see the option when selectin some code.

Comment: @user I just noticed the feature, there was another question (it seems that I didn't search properly) that answers my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70987529/check-git-history-for-a-range-of-lines-in-vscode

Comment: Note: Explicit software recommendation questions are **off-topic** on Stack Overflow for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of ways, you can install the plugin separately named as: [Git History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory)

apply it inside `VS Code` and use according to your needs:

[image]

*Source* link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory

Comment: This shows history for a single line, not a selection of lines. When selecting multiple lines and showing history for line it shows the history of the right-clicked line, not the selection.

Comment: @RabidTunes, I got your point here. I'll update my answer without any problem if I find something related to selection of lines.

Comment: I appreciate the effort very much, however, as I marked, it seems that there's a question that already has my answer, adding Gitlens and using the Git tab with Line history enabled did the trick for me.