# Preserve the sequence of Git commit messages when moving a function between modules

Tags: git, pycharm, commit

I have functions and classes organized in dedicated modules for my project. I code in Python using PyCharm.

I often need to do reorganization of the modules in my project.

Using Git, how to preserve all the commit messages when moving functions from one module to another? Apparently that it doesn't happen automatically ([ref on intellj](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000133970-Following-GIT-moves-renames-via-version-control-log)).

---

I came up with this workaround:

- Since I can see the history of a single function inside the module ([ref on stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781405/git-how-do-i-view-the-change-history-of-a-method-function) I issue the following command in a terminal:

  ```
  git log -L :myfunction:path/to/myfile.py --follow path/to/myfile.py >> myfunction_commit_history.txt
  ```
- I move myfunction to my_newfile (using PyCharm GUI, but same applies if moving it via command line)
- I copy the commit history from the myfunction_commit_history file

It's not great but better than losing the entire commit history.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *preserve commit history* in Git is nonsense.

The reason is that commits *are* history; history is nothing *but* commits.  You either have the commits, so everything is preserved, or you don't, so it's not.

What people usually mean by this is: *I renamed some file, and now I can't find it.*  That's not surprising, because each Git commit is just a snapshot of all files.  Commit `A` has files `README.txt` and `starter.py`, and commit `Z` at the end has `README.rst` and `alldone.py`.  If `README.rst` was a rename (and perhaps modify as well) somewhere along the way, well, the only way to *find* that is for Git to walk, one commit at a time, from `Z` back to `Y` back to `X` until, at some point—say between `M` and `N`—comparing the contents of the two commits shows that, *wha-hey*, `README.txt` in `M` is an awful lot like `README.rst` in `N`, so let's call that a *rename* and stop looking for `README.rst` and start looking for `README.txt` instead.  That's what `git log --follow` does.

If you jump straight from `Z` to `A`, the contents of the two files may differ too much to match them up.  But that's OK as far as *Git* is concerned: if you ask *how do I edit the files in `A` to make them look like the files in `Z`*, Git will say, *remove `README.txt` and create a new `README.rst` with these contents* and **those instructions work**.  They don't tell you want you wanted to know, but they're good enough, as far as Git is concerned.

When you move functions from one file to another, some parts of Git, including `git blame`, can do commit-by-commit comparisons, search *all* the files in the earlier commit, and find this (for `git blame` you need the `-C` option, vs the `--follow` one for `git log`).  Other parts of Git, including diffing an early commit directly against a late commit, often can't: when comparing any pair of commits, the renamed file must be sufficiently similar to the original file for the `-M` / `--find-renames` option to work.  You *can* adjust the rename-finding threshold: `-M`, when turned on without any threshold, uses a 50% similarity index, i.e., about half of the file must be the same in the two commits for Git to call that a *rename* operation.  But this rename detection requires several other conditions to hold as well.  Typically, moving a function from one existing file to another existing file will cause it to fail.  For `git diff` you can sometimes use `-B` as well (the break-pairings flag, which takes up to two similarity index values), but the usefulness of this diminishes pretty rapidly.

Comment: Is it better if I rename the title as "preserve commit messages of moved function" ? That's indeed what I want to keep when I move the function

Comment: That's definitely more sensible, but there's no way to do it, because the commit *messages* are attached to the *commits*.