# Can ack/ag/grep print function name?

Tags: linux, search, grep, ack, ag

Is it possible to print the function or class name in which a keyword occurs when using `ack` or `ag`? This is something I have highly desired for quite some time.

I think it would be quite tricky, as different programming languages have different ways of enclosing functions/classes.

Note that my goal right is for searching through C source code, however I would prefer a generic solution which covers more languages/syntax.

Comment: A tool which does not know the underlying language grammar would not be able to do this, clearly ack/ag can't do this inherently

Comment: @Inian Are there any alternatives to `ack`/`ag` which have the grammar knowledge?

Comment: If `git -L` can do it as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781405/git-how-do-i-view-the-change-history-of-a-method-function) why can't ack?

Comment: @mmigdol Wow. That's amazing. Git continues to amaze me! You may want to mention this as an answer by explaining how this would solve our problem.

Answer (score 4):

Author of ack here. No, I don't know of any greplike tool that understands anything about the text files that it's searching.  It's something that people ask for all the time, but I've never even thought about implementing it.

You said "I think it would be quite tricky, as different programming languages have different ways of enclosing functions/classes."  You're exactly right. Also, consider things like comments

> /* void foo() */

and literal strings

> printf( "void foo()" );

that would cause problems for any search tool.  Neither of those instances of the string `void foo()` is actually a function declaration.

Check out the [More Tools](https://beyondgrep.com/more-tools/) page on beyondgrep.com.  Something like [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) might help you.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Lester. The "More Tools" page on beyondgrep.com is really comprehensive :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you find it useful. You may also be interested in a similar project I've started at https://altbox.dev/, which is alternate *nix tools.

Comment: Wow!! That is some killer list at altbox.dev :)

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Inian, it would be difficult to get a robust solution using `ack`, `ag` and `grep` as they are not aware of the grammar of the languages.

However, for my case of looking inside C source code files, I used `ack` with an `OR` condition to include lines which are starting with the function definitions. In my case, all my functions were either returning `int` or nothing. Hence, the following code printed out function definition lines alongwith the lines containing the `KEYWORD`:

```sh
ack 'KEYWORD|^void|^int'
```

Answer (score 2):

Although none of the programs you listed currently have this functionality, Git uses language-based regexps to implement `git grep -L` (search within a function name).  [This blog post](https://hoelz.ro/blog/how-does-git-know-what-functions-look-like) describes how it works.  The current list of regexps are in the git source tree [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/userdiff.c), and can be extended as described in the blog above.

Also, [ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) provides a universal way to enumerate tags from files of multiple languages, but I haven't (yet) found a way to integrate this output with `git grep -L` yet.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into how we can utilize `git` for our case.